# Activity indicator with custom image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am loading a `UIWebView` and in the meantime I wan't to show a blank page with this[image: spinner] activity indicator spinning (siri activity indicator). From what I have understand you can not change the image, but can't I use that image and create an animation with it rotating 360° and looping? Or will that drain the battery?

something like this?:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    //set up animation        
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingImage];
    //start animation
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
    //stop animation
    [self.loadingImage removeFromSuperview];
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Most of this is found in Stack Overflow. Let me summarize:

Create an UIImageView which will serve as an activity indicator (inside storyboard scene, NIB, code ... wherever you wish). Let's call it `_activityIndicatorImage`

Load your image: `_activityIndicatorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"activity_indicator"]];`

You need to use animation to rotate it. Here is the method I use:

```
+ (void)rotateLayerInfinite:(CALayer *)layer
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.duration = 0.7f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    [layer removeAllAnimations];
    [layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
}
```

Inside my layoutSubviews method I initiate rotation. You could place this in your `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` if this is better for your case:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // some other code 

    [Utils rotateLayerInfinite:_activityIndicatorImage.layer];
}
```

You could always always stop rotation using `[_activityIndicatorImage.layer removeAllAnimations];`

Comment: `[Utils rotateLayerInfinite:_activityIndicatorImage.layer];` doesn't recognize the identifier "utils" ? do I have to import something? thanks again

Comment: Nope `Utils` is my class where I put the `+ (void)rotateLayerInfinite:(CALayer *)layer` code. You could use `[self.class rotateLayerInfinite:_activityIndicatorImage.layer];` if you are using it in the same class.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this beautiful **loader** inspired from **Tumblr app**:
[Asich/AMTumblrHud](https://github.com/Asich/AMTumblrHud)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Another answer working perfect

**Step 1.**

Create swift file "CustomLoader.swift" and put this code in that file

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore

class CustomLoader: UIView
{
    //MARK:- NOT ACCESSABLE OUT SIDE

    fileprivate var duration : CFTimeInterval! = 1
    fileprivate var isAnimating :Bool = false
    fileprivate var backgroundView : UIView!

    //MARK:- ACCESS INSTANCE ONLY AND CHANGE ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS   *******
    let colors : [UIColor] = [.red,  .blue,  .orange, .purple]
    var defaultColor : UIColor = UIColor.red
    var isUsrInteractionEnable : Bool = false
    var defaultbgColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var loaderSize : CGFloat = 80.0
    /// **************** ******************  ////////// **************

    //MARK:- MAKE SHARED INSTANCE
    private static var Instance : CustomLoader!
    static let sharedInstance : CustomLoader = {

        if Instance == nil
        {
            Instance = CustomLoader()
        }

        return Instance
    }()

    //MARK:- DESTROY TO SHARED INSTANCE
    @objc fileprivate func destroyShardInstance()
    {
        CustomLoader.Instance = nil
    }

    //MARK:- SET YOUR LOADER INITIALIZER FRAME ELSE DEFAULT IS CENTER
    func startAnimation()
    {
        let win = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

        backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.frame = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame)!
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0, alpha: 0.4)
        win?.addSubview(backgroundView)

        self.frame = CGRect.init(x: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - loaderSize)/2, y: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height) - loaderSize)/2, width: loaderSize, height: loaderSize)

        self.addCenterImage()
        self.isHidden = false
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(self)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = loaderSize/2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        backgroundView.accessibilityIdentifier = "CustomLoader"

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.NSExtensionHostDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CustomLoader.ResumeLoader), name: NSNotification.Name.NSExtensionHostDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

        self.layoutSubviews()
    }

    //MARK:- AVOID STUCKING LOADER WHEN CAME BACK FROM BACKGROUND
    @objc fileprivate func ResumeLoader()
    {
        if isAnimating
        {
            self.stopAnimation()
            self.AnimationStart()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.backgroundColor = defaultbgColor
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUsrInteractionEnable
        self.AnimationStart()
    }

    @objc fileprivate func addCenterImage()
    {
        /// add image in center
        let centerImage = UIImage(named: "Logo")
        let imageSize = loaderSize/2.5

        let centerImgView = UIImageView(image: centerImage)
        centerImgView.frame = CGRect(
            x: (self.bounds.width - imageSize) / 2 ,
            y: (self.bounds.height - imageSize) / 2,
            width: imageSize,
            height: imageSize
        )

        centerImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        centerImgView.layer.cornerRadius = imageSize/2
        centerImgView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(centerImgView)

    }


    //MARK:- CALL IT TO START THE LOADER , AFTER INITIALIZE THE LOADER
    @objc fileprivate func AnimationStart()
    {
        if isAnimating
        {
            return
        }

        let size = CGSize.init(width: loaderSize , height: loaderSize)

        let dotNum: CGFloat = 10
        let diameter: CGFloat = size.width / 5.5   //10

        let dot = CALayer()
        let frame = CGRect(
            x: (layer.bounds.width - diameter) / 2 + diameter * 2,
            y: (layer.bounds.height - diameter) / 2,
            width: diameter/1.3,
            height: diameter/1.3
        )

        dot.backgroundColor = colors[0].cgColor
        dot.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
        dot.frame = frame

        let replicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()
        replicatorLayer.frame = layer.bounds
        replicatorLayer.instanceCount = Int(dotNum)
        replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = 0.1

        let angle = (2.0 * M_PI) / Double(replicatorLayer.instanceCount)

        replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        layer.addSublayer(replicatorLayer)
        replicatorLayer.addSublayer(dot)

        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimation.toValue = 0.4
        scaleAnimation.duration = 0.5
        scaleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        scaleAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        dot.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scaleAnimation")

        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.toValue = -2.0 * Double.pi
        rotationAnimation.duration = 6.0
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        replicatorLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")

        if colors.count > 1 {

            var cgColors : [CGColor] = []
            for color in colors {
                cgColors.append(color.cgColor)
            }

            let colorAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
            colorAnimation.values = cgColors
            colorAnimation.duration = 2
            colorAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
            colorAnimation.autoreverses = true
            dot.add(colorAnimation, forKey: "colorAnimation")

        }

        self.isAnimating = true
        self.isHidden = false

    }


    //MARK:- CALL IT TO STOP THE LOADER
    func stopAnimation()
    {
        if !isAnimating
        {
            return
        }
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let winSubviews = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews
        if (winSubviews?.count)! > 0
        {
            for viw in winSubviews!
            {
                if viw.accessibilityIdentifier == "CustomLoader"
                {
                    viw.removeFromSuperview()
                    //  break
                }
            }
        }

        layer.sublayers = nil

        isAnimating = false
        self.isHidden = true

        self.destroyShardInstance()
    }
    //MARK:- GETTING RANDOM COLOR , AND MANAGE YOUR OWN COLORS
    @objc fileprivate func randomColor()->UIColor
    {
        let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
    }
}
```

find the func name and "**addCenterImage**" and replace the image name with your custom image.

**Step 2**

Create the AppDelegate class instance out side of the AppDelegate class like this.

```
var AppInstance: AppDelegate!
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    AppInstance = self
}
```

**Step 3.**

put these two func in your AppDelegate

```
//MARK: - Activity Indicator -
    func showLoader()
    {
        CustomLoader.sharedInstance.startAnimation()
    }
    func hideLoader()
    {
        CustomLoader.sharedInstance.stopAnimation()
    }
```

Step 4. Use the functions like this whenever you want to animate your loader and stop.

```
AppInstance.showLoader()
AppInstance.hideLoader()
```

**HAPPY LOADING...**

Comment: I want to rotate anticlockwise so where can change in code?

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4 Sweet And Simply just put extension UIView{}**

Modified answer of **@gandhi Mena**

if you want to create your own custom Loading indicator

Create a UIView extension which create and customize your brand logo as a custom indicator put this code in you global declaration file.

```
extension UIView{
func customActivityIndicator(view: UIView, widthView: CGFloat?,backgroundColor: UIColor?, textColor:UIColor?, message: String?) -> UIView{

    //Config UIView
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor //Background color of your view which you want to set

    var selfWidth = view.frame.width
    if widthView != nil{
        selfWidth = widthView ?? selfWidth
    }

    let selfHeigh = view.frame.height
    let loopImages = UIImageView()

    let imageListArray = ["image1", "image2"] // Put your desired array of images in a specific order the way you want to display animation.

    loopImages.animationImages = imageListArray
    loopImages.animationDuration = TimeInterval(0.8)
    loopImages.startAnimating()

    let imageFrameX = (selfWidth / 2) - 30
    let imageFrameY = (selfHeigh / 2) - 60
    var imageWidth = CGFloat(60)
    var imageHeight = CGFloat(60)

    if widthView != nil{
        imageWidth = widthView ?? imageWidth
        imageHeight = widthView ?? imageHeight
    }

    //ConfigureLabel
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 17.0)! // Your Desired UIFont Style and Size
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = message ?? ""
    label.textColor = textColor ?? UIColor.clear

    //Config frame of label
    let labelFrameX = (selfWidth / 2) - 100
    let labelFrameY = (selfHeigh / 2) - 10
    let labelWidth = CGFloat(200)
    let labelHeight = CGFloat(70)

    // Define UIView frame
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)


    //ImageFrame
    loopImages.frame = CGRect(x: imageFrameX, y: imageFrameY, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

    //LabelFrame
    label.frame = CGRect(x: labelFrameX, y: labelFrameY, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)

    //add loading and label to customView
    self.addSubview(loopImages)
    self.addSubview(label)
    return self }}
```

Hide an indicator something like this you can remove subview at the top from the subview stack. put this code in the same globally declared swift file.

```
func hideLoader(removeFrom : UIView){
removeFrom.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Now you can shoot at the mark by this code 
To display activity indicator in your view controller put this code when you want to display.

```
 self.view.addSubview(UIView().customActivityIndicator(view: self.view, widthView: nil, backgroundColor:"Desired color", textColor: "Desired color", message: "Loading something"))
```

To hide animating loader you can user above function you defined in the globally. In your **ViewController.swift** where you want to hide put this line of code.

```
hideLoader(removeFrom: self.view)
```

imageListArray looks like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting solution. To get it to work for me I had to refactor and modify slightly. First "Screen Size" had to be removed. I simply set self.frame to the view.frame. Then I deleted the font line. Next I needed to be able to remove the activity indicator without assuming it was the last of the subviews. To do this I created a custom subclass of UIView and used the same code. Then when I went to remove the activity indicator I looped through the subviews looking for one of my custom type.

Comment: @Allen thats great brother will you share your source me @ azusam75@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.0 version of accepted Answer

```
public extension UIImageView {
  func spin(duration: Float) {
    let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotation.fromValue = 0
    rotation.toValue = 2 * Double.pi
    rotation.duration = 0.7
    rotation.repeatCount = duration
    layer.add(rotation, forKey: "spin")
  }

  func stopSpinning() {
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I start animation of the image? I have called myImageView.spin(), but it doesn't spin.

Comment: It started working after I added this:
`rotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false`

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar issue lately. And this is my solution. Basically, it's what topic starter initially wanted: blank page with custom activity indicator on it.
I have partly used @Azharhussain Shaikh answer but I've implemented auto-layout instead of using frames and added a few other refinements with the intention to make usage as simple as possible.

So, it's an extension for UIView with two methods: **addActivityIndicator()** and **removeActivityIndicator()**

```
extension UIView {

func addActivityIndicator() {
    //    creating a view (let's call it "loading" view) which will be added on top of the view you want to have activity indicator on (parent view)
    let view = UIView()
    //    setting up a background for a view so it would make content under it look like not active
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

    //    adding "loading" view to a parent view
    //    setting up auto-layout anchors so it would cover whole parent view
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    //    creating array with images, which will be animated
    //    in my case I have 30 images with names activity0.png ... activity29.png
    var imagesArray = [UIImage(named: "activity\(0)")!]
    for i in 1..<30 {
        imagesArray.append(UIImage(named: "activity\(i)")!)
    }

    //    creating UIImageView with array of images
    //    setting up animation duration and starting animation
    let activityImage = UIImageView()
    activityImage.animationImages = imagesArray
    activityImage.animationDuration = TimeInterval(0.7)
    activityImage.startAnimating()

    //    adding UIImageView on "loading" view
    //    setting up auto-layout anchors so it would be in center of "loading" view with 30x30 size
    view.addSubview(activityImage)
    activityImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    activityImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    activityImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    activityImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    activityImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}

func removeActivityIndicator() {
    //    checking if a view has subviews on it
    guard let lastSubView = self.subviews.last else { return }
    //    removing last subview with an assumption that last view is a "loading" view
    lastSubView.removeFromSuperview()
} }
```

"Rotating" effect is achieved by those 30 images you've put in imagesArray. Each image is a new frame of a rotating indicator [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wDrU.png).

**Usage**. In your view controller for showing an activity indicator simply put:

```
    view.addActivityIndicator()
```

For removing an activity indicator:

```
    view.removeActivityIndicator()
```

For example, in case of using it with table view (like I do) it can be used like this:

```
func setLoadingScreen() {
    view.addActivityIndicator()
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

func removeLoadingScreen() {
    view.removeActivityIndicator()
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

It works in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

Without Image , you can use third party library

for objective C (also support in iOS 6)  https://github.com/shebinkoshy/UIControllsRepo

for swift https://github.com/shebinkoshy/Activity-Indicator-Swift

**Advantages**

-> Able to set colors for spinner

-> Available in different sizes like tiny, small, medium, large, very large

-> Able to set Title (center and bottom) for medium, large, very large sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can set an **images** to your `activityIndicator`. I created a function for **add custom image** to activityIndicator. Here is what I created.

```
public func showProgressView(view: UIView) -> UIImageView {
    let containerView = UIView()
    let progressView = UIView()
    var activityIndicatorImageView = UIImageView()

    if let statusImage = UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName1) {
        let activityImageView = UIImageView(image: statusImage)
        containerView.frame = view.frame
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)
        progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
        progressView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.width / 2, view.bounds.height / 2)
        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x18bda3, alpha: 0.7)
        progressView.clipsToBounds = true
        progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        activityImageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName1)!,
            UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName2)!,
            UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName3)!,
            UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName4)!,
            UIImage(named: Constants.ActivityIndicatorImageName5)!]
        activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.8;
        activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width / 2 - statusImage.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2 - statusImage.size.height / 2, 40.0, 48.0)
        activityImageView.center = CGPointMake(progressView.bounds.width / 2, progressView.bounds.height / 2)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            progressView.addSubview(activityImageView)
            containerView.addSubview(progressView)
            view.addSubview(containerView)
            activityIndicatorImageView = activityImageView
        }
    }
    return activityIndicatorImageView
}
```

You can call this method everywhere in your code. And just call the `startAnimating` method. If you want to hide just call the `stopAnimating` method.

Answer (score 0):

**it works in both SWITF 3 and 4**

```
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var myView : UIView = UIView()

func viewDidLoad() {
    spinnerCreation()
}

func spinnerCreation() {

    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle =  .whiteLarge

    let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 60, width: 90, height: 20))
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = "Please wait...."

    myView.frame = CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 100)/2, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 100)/2, width: 100, height: 100)

    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.7)
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: myView.frame.size.width/2, y:  myView.frame.size.height/2 - 10)
    myView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    myView.addSubview(label)

    myView.isHidden = true
    self.window?.addSubview(myView)
}

@IBAction func activityIndicatorStart(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.isHidden = false
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: myView)
}

@IBAction func activityIndicatorStop(_ sender: Any)() {
    myView.isHidden = true
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: This code does not add a custom image, only adds a layer in the back of the system Activity Indicator

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom activity Indicator with this in **Swift 3 & 4**:

Create a new file with name: UIViewExtension.Swift and copy this code and paste in your new file file:

```
import UIkit

extension UIView{
   func customActivityIndicator(view: UIView, widthView: CGFloat? = nil,backgroundColor: UIColor? = nil, message: String? = nil,colorMessage:UIColor? = nil ) -> UIView{

    //Config UIView
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor ?? UIColor.clear
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10


    var selfWidth = view.frame.width - 100
    if widthView != nil{
        selfWidth = widthView ?? selfWidth
    }

    let selfHeigh = CGFloat(100)
    let selfFrameX = (view.frame.width / 2) - (selfWidth / 2)
    let selfFrameY = (view.frame.height / 2) - (selfHeigh / 2)
    let loopImages = UIImageView()

    //ConfigCustomLoading with secuence images
    let imageListArray = [UIImage(named:""),UIImage(named:""), UIImage(named:"")]
    loopImages.animationImages = imageListArray
    loopImages.animationDuration = TimeInterval(1.3)
    loopImages.startAnimating()
    let imageFrameX = (selfWidth / 2) - 17
    let imageFrameY = (selfHeigh / 2) - 35
    var imageWidth = CGFloat(35)
    var imageHeight = CGFloat(35)

    if widthView != nil{
        imageWidth = widthView ?? imageWidth
        imageHeight = widthView ?? imageHeight
    }

    //ConfigureLabel
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = message ?? ""
    label.textColor = colorMessage ?? UIColor.clear

    //Config frame of label
    let labelFrameX = (selfWidth / 2) - 100
    let labelFrameY = (selfHeigh / 2) - 10
    let labelWidth = CGFloat(200)
    let labelHeight = CGFloat(70)

    //add loading and label to customView
    self.addSubview(loopImages)
    self.addSubview(label)

    //Define frames
    //UIViewFrame
    self.frame = CGRect(x: selfFrameX, y: selfFrameY, width: selfWidth , height: selfHeigh)

    //ImageFrame
    loopImages.frame = CGRect(x: imageFrameX, y: imageFrameY, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

    //LabelFrame
    label.frame = CGRect(x: labelFrameX, y: labelFrameY, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)

    return self

}

}
```

And then you can use it in your ViewController like this:

```
import UIKit


class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(UIView().customActivityIndicator(view: self.view,backgroundColor: UIColor.green))

    }

   //function for stop and desappear loading
   func deseappearLoading(){
      self.view.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Don't forget replace [UIImage(named:" "),UIImage(named:" "), UIImage(named:" ")] with your names of images and adjust the TimeInterval(1.3). Enjoy it.