# Spin image but not continuously in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm looking for animate an image endless with 30 degrees turns. I only have found smooth spins solutions by using CABasicAnimation ([Activity indicator with custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206745/activity-indicator-with-custom-image))

Comment: Did you noticed the "repeatCount" in your [provided question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206745/activity-indicator-with-custom-image)'s answer?

Comment: Yes. I don't mean about repeat times. I mean about moving it in steps of 30 degrees and not doing it smoothly.